# Show that if five points are placed in a Equilateral triangle with sides of 2, two points will always be closer than 1

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, education

I don't know where to start.

i know that I am supposed to use some sort of probability principal.

Comment: Try to divide an equilateral triangle into four equal parts, each of which is an equilateral triangle of side $1$. Now, if there are five points, then two of these must lie within the same equilateral triangle, since we have five points, which is more than four triangles. Prove that any two points within an equilateral triangle of side $1$ cannot be separated by more than $1$ unit. Then you would be done.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: this is woth as answer more than comment

Answer (score 1):

- Try to divide an equilateral triangle into four equal parts, each of which is an equilateral triangle of side $1$.
- Now, if there are five points, then two of these must lie within the same equilateral triangle, since we have five points, which is more than four triangles.
- Prove that any two points within an equilateral triangle of side $1$ cannot be separated by more than $1$ unit.
  Then you would be done.

Comment: thank you! but how do i show that mathematically?

Comment: The division is not difficult : if you have an equilateral triangle of side $2$, then join the midpoints of all sides to each other : this gives four equilateral triangles of side $1$, like three on the corners and one in the middle. To show the third part, look at this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1685474/316409